# how can I sign-out from google account from a different page?

Tags: javascript, php, google-signin

I've implied Google Sign-in to my website successfully, and the Signout is working as well as far as they both are on the same page.
I have a Navbar on the website which is included on top of every page(including the sign-in page), I want to locate the sign-out button on the Navbar, but when I do this, it doesn't work anymore.
since I'm using PHP, I've tried setting a `header('location:login.php');` where both the Sign-in and Sign-out buttons are, and then using
`<script src="'.$js.'script.js"></script> // this is my js script where the signOut() function is declared  <script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = signOut; </script>`
and it didnt work,
I also tried to trigger the Sign-out button with `document.getElementById("google_signout").click;` after the user has been sent there with the php punction `header('location:login.php');` and it didnt work as well.
whats the correct way to do it?
By the way, I'm writing the Javascript code within PHP code, so like this:

```
   <?php
       if (isset($_SESSION['User'])){ // run this if the user is logged in 

            echo '<script src="'.$js.'script.js"></script> //load my script where the google signOut() is declared  
            <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = signOut;
            </script>';
    }else{
      //do something else
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Twice you wrote `windo.onload` - is this in actual code or just an error while writing the question?

Comment: nono in the code it is `window.onload`